# Custom TCP/IP server in django webapp?

Tags: python, django

I was going to write this website for communicating with others and i want to implement a desktop app too so now I was wondering whether is is possible to integrate a python, maybe twisted tcp ip server within django so that both the site and the custom tcp could run alongside each other...?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you running your Django application?

Comment: the plan was to use unicorn with nginx for load distributions... but it would be nice if testable with the run server command...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What for. Make your desktop app speak HTTP and use an alternate API provided by another application.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

http://www.clemesha.org/blog/realtime-web-apps-python-django-orbited-twisted

these two things helped a lot for me.. and i am pretty sure i can fix it now

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)-y methods that work on top of HTTP for (almost-)realtime communication if you don't want to go through the hassle (and possible fragility) of your own TCP/IP server.

Answer (score -1):

[imdjango](https://github.com/acuros/imdjango) (Instantly-made Mobile-server on Django) project started yesterday.
You may use it to make both mobile server and web server on one django project.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about how this would answer the OP's question?